# Can custom decorator access parts of $content

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-decorators

In a custom decorator, I'm wrapping the element content with a div. This code creates a `div` around both the `<dt> label` and the `<dd> element`

```
public function render($content)
{        
   return '<div class="test">' . $content . '</div>';
}
```

Is there a way I can further access those 2 parts, the dd and dt. Such as maybe wrap the div around only the `<dt>` or the `<dd>`. How do I access the different parts of `$content`?

Comment: It's `<!ELEMENT DL - - (DT|DD)+ -- definition list -->`, so wrapping the div around a dt or dd would produce invalid markup.

Comment: @Gordon, I agree, but I still need to access those individual parts of content so I can try and do something with them

Comment: I am not sure if you can stack the HtmlTag decorators to wrap a div around the label and the element each. The Label itself is a decorator too. But you can definitely write your own custom label decorator. Basically it's all in the second article I gave you yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is not that necessary to create a custom decorator for what you want to achieve, you can try decorating the element directly like the following:

`$elementDecorators = array(
   'ViewHelper',
   array(array('element'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'dd')),
   array('Label', array('tag' => 'dt')),
   array(array('wrapper'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div')),
);`

that shud produce a markup like so:

`<div>
   <dt><label/></dt>
   <dd><input/></dd>
</div>`

and so if you want to add anything you want within/between/before/after the dd or dt you can modify as thus:

`$elementDecorators = array(
   'ViewHelper',
   array(array('addition'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'span')),
   array(array('element'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'dd')),
   array('Label', array('tag' => 'dt')),
   array(array('wrapper'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div')),
);`

that shud produce:

`<div>
   <dt><label/></dt>
   <dd><span><input/></span></dd>
</div>`

which just wraps a span tag around the element before the dd tag does.

after decorating you can simply add the variable as the decorator of the element.